# How Do I Use System Variables In Delphi Search Path?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, search-path

In Delphi XE2 I am setting up a search path. I would like to use a system variable, that I define, to shorten the strings of the various folders used in the search path.

I do it like this:

```
Search path         : x:\Delphi Library\XTools;x:\Delphi Library\XDiag;
I define variable   : L = x:\Delphi Library
Search path using L : $(L)\XTools;$(L)\XDiag;
```

If I don't use the defined environment variable, that is write out the path in full, all is well but if i do use the environment variable the compiler does not  understand the search path.

I have been using Delphi 3 which is considerably simpler than XE2 so perhaps I'm not specifying either the path or the variable in exactly the right place:

Path is specified here:

> Project Manager|Project|Options|Delphi Compiler|Target All
>   Configurations - All Platforms|Search Path

Variable is specified here:

> Project Manager|Project|Options|Debugger|Target: All Configurations -
>   All Platforms|Environment Block|User Overrides

Comment: You specified the variable for the debugged process. You should instead specify it for Delphi's process, in Tools\Options\Environment as Rudy answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just did the following, in XE2:

- In `Tools|Options|Environment variables`, I defined a user override to the directory of my [`AutoConsole.pas`](http://rvelthuis.blogspot.de/2016/07/new-velthuisautoconsole-unit.html) unit, as new variable `L`.
- In the options of a completely new console project, I defined the search path as `$(L)`
- added `AutoConsole` to the `uses` clause of that project
- I compiled the project without any problem, and `AutoConsole` did what it should do: it presented me with a message `Press any key...` and waited for a keypress.
- Then I removed `$(L)` from the search path
- The program did not compile anymore, because it could not find `AutoConsole`.
- I re-added `$(L)` and the program compiled and worked again.

So what you wanted to do should work. I have no idea what you did wrong, but if you do things like I did, it should work.